# Import Array to Realm

Tags: objective-c, realm

Is it possible to import a set of Arrays to Realm instead of just a single Object? It is because I retrieved a set of static data as JSON and converted to Array.

However, I only find this method is available for import an Object.

```
(instancetype)createOrUpdateInRealm:(RLMRealm *)realm withObject:(id)object
```

Any method is for Array?

Thanks
Alex

Comment: No. BTW, I found out this great library could help. It allows your to import a JSON array and it solve my problem now. https://github.com/matthewcheok/Realm-JSON

Comment: also https://github.com/erkie/ApiModel

Answer (score 0):

The only criteria here is DataType and the name of the key in the JSON should match the DataType and name of the key that you created in the Realm Model.

```
    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    [realm beginWriteTransaction];
    [YourRealmModelName createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:[json valueForKey:@"key"]];
    [realm commitWriteTransaction];
```